# Showing that the complete bipartite graph $K_{a,b}$ is a tree if and only if $a=1$ or $b=1$.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let $K_{a,b}$ be the complete bipartite graph. Show that
$K_{a,b}$ is a tree if and only if $a = 1$ or $b = 1$.

The way my professor showed us for a complete graph is as below. I just don't know how to start for a complete bipartite graph.

> $K_a$ is a tree if and only if $a=2$ or $a=1$.

*Proof:* For all $u\in V(K_a)$, $\deg(u) = a-1$ implies that $$2|E(K_a)| = \sum \deg(u) = (a-1)|V(K_a)|=a(a-1),$$ so $|E(K_a)|=\frac{a(a-1)}{2}.$

Since $K_a$ is connected, it is a tree if and only if \begin{eqnarray*} 0 &=&|E(K_a)| -|V(K_a)| +1 \\
&=& a(a-1)/2 -a +1 \\ 
&=& \frac{1}{2}(a(a-1)-2a+2)\\
&=& 1/2[a(a-1)-2(a-2)] \\
&=& 1/2[(a-1)(a-2)] =0 \end{eqnarray*}

Thus $K_a$ is a tree if and only if $a-1=0$ or $a-2=0,$ i.e., $a=1$ or $a=2$.

> $K_{a,b}$ is a tree if and only if $a=1$ or $b=1$.

*Proof:* For all $u,v \in V(K_{a,b})$, $\deg(u) = a$ and $\deg(v) = b $ implies that $$2|E(K_{a,b})| = \sum \deg(u) + \sum \deg(v)= ab+ab=2ab,$$ so $|E(K_{a,b})|=ab.$

Since $K_{a,b}$ is connected, it is a tree if and only if \begin{eqnarray*} 0 &=&|E(K_{a,b})| -|V(K_{a,b})| +1 \\
&=& ab-a-b +1 \\ 
&=& (a-1)(b-1)=0\end{eqnarray*}

Thus $K_{a,b}$ is a tree if and only if $a-1=0$ or $b-1=0,$ i.e., $a=1$ or $b=1$.

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: The way my professor showed us for a complete graph was, like this. I just don't know how to start for a complete bipartite graph.

Show that 
Ka is a tree ⇔ a=2 ∨ a=1

∀u∈V(Ka) : d(u) = a-1 ⇒2|E(Ka)| = ∑ d(u) = (a-1) |V(Ka)| = a(a-1)⇒a(a-1)/2 

Also have |V(Ka)| = a

|E(Ka)| -|V(Ka)| +1 = a(a-1)/2 -a +1 
= 1/2[a(a-1)-2a+2] 
= 1/2[a(a-1)-2(a-2)] 
= 1/2[(a-1)(a-2)] =0 

Ka is a tree ⇔ a-1=0∨a-2=0 
⇔a =1 ∨ a=2

Comment: Sorry I can't get the break line to work

Comment: @Daniel : Well, you should edit your post with this comment then.  I gave up on reading it :)

Comment: Hint if you want to approach your question in the same way as your prof: notice that $ab-a-b+1=(a-1)(b-1)$

Comment: @ManuelLafond : I edited my original post, hope that helps :)

Comment: I've edited your post. In the future, you may want to study the mathjax/latex tags I used to make your post more readable. I've also removed some of the short-hand symbols you used (e.g., $\iff, \vee, \forall$) and replaced them with actual words. In general, this makes your work much more readable; save those short-hand symbols for your own rough work.

Comment: Do you understand your teacher's proof ?  As Casteels' hint suggests, you can do the exact same thing, except that you need to find the values of $|E(K_{a,b})|$ and $|V(K_{a,b})|$.

Comment: Sorry for the late respond, I've been studying for a Differential equations test. I'll post what I have done so far soon.

Comment: @Casteels : Thank you. I definitely will, it's very useful. I agree about the short hand notations, I just wanted to show how it was presented to me.

ManuelLafond : Yes, after a more careful read through I understood it more. Thank you.
I re-edited my post with what I was able to come up with.

Answer (score 7):

Number of edges in a complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ is $mn$.

Number of edges in a tree with $v$ vertices is $v-1$.

Hence, if we want $K_{a,b}$ to be a tree, we need

$$ab = a+b-1 \implies ab-a-b+1 = 0\implies (a-1)(b-1) = 0 \implies a = 1 \text{ or }b=1$$

Answer (score 0):

If $a>1$ and $b>1$, then let $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_s\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\dots,b_t\}$ be the two parts of vertices with $s>1$ and $t>1$. We can then find a circuit in the graph, say $a_1b_1a_2b_2a_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the first set have nodes $v_1,v_2,...v_a$ and the second set have nodes $w_1,w_2,....w_b$.

1. Now if both $a$ and $b$ are greater than one then you always find a cycle in the graph , take the minimal case $a=b=2$, then you would have a cycle $(v_1,w_1),(w_1,v_2),(v_2,w_2),(w_2,v_1)$ , here $(i,j)$ means edge between node $i$ and $j$. Thus for every case where $a>=2 , b>=2$ you will find a cycle and graph is not a tree.
2. If both $a=b=1$ it is trivial to see the graph is a tree.
3. Last case is exactly one of $a$ and $b$ is equal to one ( say $a$=1 and $b \ne 1$ ). In this case it is again it is trivial to see graph is tree, its a simple graph which is connected and number of nodes is $b+1$ and number of edges $b$ ( one less than number of nodes ) thus it is a tree.